# Can't install ionic-service-deploy

Tags: ionic-framework, npm, bower

I am using ionic and wanted to add deploy option to my code but can't install
ionic-service-deploy.
I am trying to run

```
ionic add ionic-service-deploy
```

but getting error:

```
> Failed to find the bower component "ionic-service-deploy".
Are you sure it exists? (CLI v1.4.5)

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 5.0.0
Ionic Version: 1.0.0
Ionic CLI Version: 1.4.5
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.0.22
OS: Windows 7 SP1
Node Version: v0.12.4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the issue was with firewall, just need to do proxy and it will solve the issue

Answer (score 2):

You must run this first:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugins-deploy
```

Source: http://docs.ionic.io/v1.0/docs/deploy-install

Comment: I run this but still get the same issue

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes if i'm on a non-windows pc at work i'm always having problems with bower and npm all i run is the command below

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```